# Microsoft runtime libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

We're writing an MFC program for a client and gave them and executable but it turns out that they need to install a runtime. I haven't time to learn how to create an installer, so I was going to try and change the Code Generation/ Run time library to /MT and take the hit on the size of the program but now I get this error,

```
fatal error C1189: #error :  Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds
```

I'm using visual studio 2010. I just want to be able to give the code (small executable) to the client and it run.

BTW, if anyone can point me in the direction of a good article on how the build an installer, I would be very grateful.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2):

The /MT applies to the C Runtime Library.  You also need to deal with the MFC library.  Configuration Properties - General - Use MFC in a Static Library.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is an article on redistributing the Visual C++ files that your client needs to run your application. Probably, the easiest option would be to get the installer from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) for the 32-bit version or [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632) for the 64-bit version. Alternatively, you if you are going to write an installer, you can use the merge modules, which should have been included with your Visual Studio.